# Have I used mixed conditional structure correctly?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

> If there **was** ample affordable housing, the rent level **would have been**
> much lower.

In the above sentence I tried to express this idea that, **currently**, there is not enough housing therefore the prices are high. I used would have been because I am going to enforce this idea that it is not possible to fix the issue anymore, because there is a shortage of housing. In other words:

- Condition: present time, it is not about the past time
- Result: A situation that cannot be changed.

Considering these points, have I used the mixed conditional correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work out hypothetical conditionals is to first think of what you want to say as a simple conditional:

> If there **is** ample affordable housing, the rent **will be** much lower.

To convert it to a hypothetical conditional, You convert the verbs to their subjunctive form. The be-verb has a special subjunctive **were**: for all other verbs, you backshift (the same as you do for [reported speech](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm)). Taking the sentence above, you get:

> If there **were** ample affordable housing, the rent **would be** much lower.

Your suggested sentence is incorrect: **was** should be **were**- though you will hear **was** in informal, spoken English.

Also, it probably doesn't mean what you want to say: **would have been** relates to a situation that happened in the past, rather than to the present.

For example, if a friend tells you that their car broke down yesterday, you could say:

> If I **had been** there, I **would have been** able to fix it for you.

---

As I understand it, a mixed hypothetical conditional is one where the two clauses relate to different times.

First, let's look at how we convert a simple (non-mixed) sentence to a simple conditional. We do it by adding **If** and a consequence-word, for example **will** or **can**.This sentence has two present tense clauses:

> I have money, I feel happy.
> If I have money, I will feel happy.

Now start with a mixed simple sentence, with a past simple clause and a present simple clause:

> I **invested** a thousand back then, I **have** nearly thirty thousand now.

We convert it to a mixed simple conditional by adding **if** and **will**. Mixed simple conditionals are grammatical but don't always make sense, as with this one:

> **If** I invested a thousand back then, I **will** have nearly thirty thousand now.

Now convert it to a mixed hypothetical conditional by adding a backshift:

> If I **had invested** a thousand back then, I **would have** nearly thirty thousand now.

Comment: But it is second conditional. I am asking about mixed conditional

Comment: @a.toraby I think that you are over-complicating things. Let me repeat what I said. Make a simple conditional that expresses what you want to say, then convert the verbs to subjunctive, as described above, to make a hypothetical conditional. This works for both second and mixed conditionals.

Comment: Thank you but you didn't say, what I have written is wrong or correct?

Comment: @a.toraby I have added a comment on your sentence to my answer.

Comment: So what is the usage of mixed conditions? Could you please give an example of mixed condition that works well!?

Comment: @a.toraby I have added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you take a look at this one too? https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/291760/6341

Comment: a.toraby that question is almost the same. Try following the steps that I have suggested in the last section of this answer, and see what you get. Edit your question to add the three stages (mixed statement, mixed simple conditional, mixed hypothetical conditional).