# Is this mixed conditional sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Consider the following sentence. I want to talk about something in future which is related to something in the past! Unfortunately the thing in the past did not happen and therefore in future it will not have impact. Is this a correct use case for mixed conditional sentence?

> If there had been ample affordable housing, the rent level will have been
> much lower this time next year.

Comment: "...the rent level _would_ have been lower..."

Comment: You have to use *would*, as Kate suggested because the events in question never happened.

Comment: I think "...would be..." fits better than "would have been", especially when it's rearranged so the reader already understands the unusual timeline when we hit that verb: "*If there had been ample affordable housing, this time next year the rent level would be much lower (than it's going to be)."

Comment: Please pay attention that I am talking about a future time! I want to say that next year the rent level will be lower. It does not refer to present if I say "would"??